# Threshold detection with reactive extensions

Tags: reactive-programming, system.reactive

I have rewritten this question after spending some time on reactive extensions - I probably know enough to now be very dangerous so please be patient and thanks in advance.

I have the following code which detects levels:

```
static class LevelExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<double> GetCrossovers(this double[] self, double x1, double x2)
    {
        return from level in self
               where level >= x1 && level <= x2 || level <= x1 && level >= x2
               select level;
    }

    public static IObservable<ThresholdCrossedEvent> ThresholdDetection(this IObservable<double> source, double[] thresholds)
    {
        return source
                .Buffer(2, 1)
                .Where(x => x.Count == 2)
                .Select(x => new { LevelsCrossed = thresholds.GetCrossovers(x[0], x[1]), Previous = x[0], Current = x[1] })
                .Where(x => x.LevelsCrossed.ToList().Count > 0)
                .SelectMany(x => from level in x.LevelsCrossed select new ThresholdCrossedEvent(level, x.Previous, x.Current));
    }
}

public class ThresholdCrossedEvent
{
    public ThresholdCrossedEvent(double level, double previous, double current)
    {

        Threshold = level;
        Previous = previous;
        Current = current;
    }

    public double Threshold { get; set; }
    public double Previous { get; set; }
    public double Current { get; set; }
    public Direction SlopeDirection => Current >= Previous ? Direction.Up : Direction.Down;
    public bool IsTouching => Current == Threshold || Previous == Threshold;
}


var feed = new double[] { 1, 2, 3, 5, 5.5, 6, 9, 12, 10, 9, 7.5, 6.5, 7 }.ToObservable();
var levels = new double[] { 5, 7, 8 };

feed
  .ThresholdDetection(levels)
  .Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(x)));
```

And it produces the events as expected, OK so far:

```
{"Threshold":5.0,"Previous":3.0,"Current":5.0,"IsUpward":true,"IsTouching":true}
{"Threshold":5.0,"Previous":5.0,"Current":5.5,"IsUpward":true,"IsTouching":true}
{"Threshold":7.0,"Previous":6.0,"Current":9.0,"IsUpward":true,"IsTouching":false}
{"Threshold":8.0,"Previous":6.0,"Current":9.0,"IsUpward":true,"IsTouching":false}
{"Threshold":8.0,"Previous":9.0,"Current":7.5,"IsUpward":false,"IsTouching":false}
{"Threshold":7.0,"Previous":7.5,"Current":6.5,"IsUpward":false,"IsTouching":false}
{"Threshold":7.0,"Previous":6.5,"Current":7.0,"IsUpward":true,"IsTouching":true}
```

**Any performance smells?**

Without prematurely optimizing - Anything else that is screaming out performance issues (as i will be processing 40,000+ messages per second)?

I note my `GetLevelsBetweenPair` level crossing detection would rely on `Linq.Where` with thousands of updates per second, and my `levels` sequence should be ordered low to high - does `Linq` optimize for me or anything I should consider?

**How would I handle the `levels` list to be updated at runtime?**

I am calling `OnNext` on my `feed` list posting values from a message bus, then via a user interface/command I add/remove an element on the `levels` list (and it would need to reorder itself atomically after modification).

Given the constant checking this will be a highly contested array (but would not be updated often at all), what things should be considered for this levels list update process?

Which structure could allow gated access in the most efficient way?

**Having different lists of `levels` and calling the same subscription on it**

I would have different "categories" of levels, each creating the same ThresholdCrossedEvent but would mean different things i.e. HistoricalThreshold or a WeeklyThreshold.

Is it OK (preferable) to do the below as multiple subscriptions, or should I encode this threshold type data into the alert and change it from a double[] to an class object that contains the requisite fields?

```
feed
  .ThresholdDetection(historicalThresholds)
  .Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine("Historical " + JsonConvert.SerializeObject(x)));

feed
  .ThresholdDetection(weeklyThresholds)
  .Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine("Weekly: " + JsonConvert.SerializeObject(x)));
```

Comment: FYI there is no use of Rx in the code above.

Comment: Thanks Slugart, unfortunately wasted my money on the Rx "expert"... Need to learn to do this myself, I'm still convinced Rx is best way to solve the requirement

Comment: I think it's the right way to go and will actually simplify your code.

Comment: This is the equivalent of a homework problem question

Comment: I understand that, but i honestly have no idea where to start - I even paid someone for this (externally, I imagine job offers are not allowed here) - any pointers on where to start so I can learn my self would be most constructively appreciated as soon as i am able will award bounty on this question also, even if it means splitting up to smaller chunks.

Comment: A marble diagram of what you're actually trying to do would help. It's not clear from your question what you're starting from, or what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Thanks for patience @Shlomo had a punt at it myself, seems to output the required data, just not sure on the implementation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your implementation looks ok. A couple things:

1. You want to model the changing `levels` as an observable as well.
2. I'm not the best Linq2Objects expert, but I think the list/array casting is unnecessary and a mild performance hit (if you're worried about that). Obviously test.
3. I hate Linq syntax so I removed it in the sample below. I don't think that matters.

The solution then looks like this:

```
static class LevelExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<double> GetCrossovers(this IEnumerable<double> self, double x1, double x2)
    {
        return self
            .Where(level => level >= x1 && level <= x2 || level <= x1 && level >= x2);
    }

    public static IObservable<ThresholdCrossedEvent> ThresholdDetection(this IObservable<double> source, IObservable<double[]> thresholdSource)
    {
        return thresholdSource
            .Select(thresholds => source
                .Buffer(2, 1)
                .Where(x => x.Count == 2)
                .Select(x => new { LevelsCrossed = thresholds.GetCrossovers(x[0], x[1]), Previous = x[0], Current = x[1] })
                .Where(x => x.LevelsCrossed.Count() > 0)
                .SelectMany(x => x.LevelsCrossed.Select(lc => new ThresholdCrossedEvent(lc, x.Previous, x.Current)))
            )
            .Switch();
    }
}
```

This is a direct adaptation of your code: The only difference is the outer `Select`, the `Switch` and the typing. For each `levels` notification, the new `Select` creates a new Observable. `Switch` means always switch to the latest one, and drop the older ones. So this way you're always using the latest `levels` thresholds.

I tested it with running the following code:

```
var feed = new double[] { 1, 2, 3, 5, 5.5, 6, 9, 12, 10, 9, 7.5, 6.5, 7 };
var levels = new double[] { 5, 7, 8 };

var feedSubject = new Subject<double>();
var levelsSubject = new BehaviorSubject<double[]>(levels);

feedSubject
    .ThresholdDetection(levelsSubject)
    .Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(x)));
    
foreach (var d in feed)
    feedSubject.OnNext(d);

levelsSubject.OnNext(new double[] { 5, 8 });
Console.WriteLine("---");

foreach (var d in feed)
    feedSubject.OnNext(d);
```

It runs through that feed array once with your original thresholds, then I run through it with the 7 threshold removed. My output is like this:

```
{"Threshold":5.0,"Previous":3.0,"Current":5.0,"SlopeDirection":0,"IsTouching":true}
{"Threshold":5.0,"Previous":5.0,"Current":5.5,"SlopeDirection":0,"IsTouching":true}
{"Threshold":7.0,"Previous":6.0,"Current":9.0,"SlopeDirection":0,"IsTouching":false}
{"Threshold":8.0,"Previous":6.0,"Current":9.0,"SlopeDirection":0,"IsTouching":false}
{"Threshold":8.0,"Previous":9.0,"Current":7.5,"SlopeDirection":1,"IsTouching":false}
{"Threshold":7.0,"Previous":7.5,"Current":6.5,"SlopeDirection":1,"IsTouching":false}
{"Threshold":7.0,"Previous":6.5,"Current":7.0,"SlopeDirection":0,"IsTouching":true}
---
{"Threshold":5.0,"Previous":3.0,"Current":5.0,"SlopeDirection":0,"IsTouching":true}
{"Threshold":5.0,"Previous":5.0,"Current":5.5,"SlopeDirection":0,"IsTouching":true}
{"Threshold":8.0,"Previous":6.0,"Current":9.0,"SlopeDirection":0,"IsTouching":false}
{"Threshold":8.0,"Previous":9.0,"Current":7.5,"SlopeDirection":1,"IsTouching":false}
```

Comment: Thank you so much really appreciate it your additions complete it! For the list casting do you mean in the GetCrossovers function? For my other question "Having different lists of levels and calling the same subscription on it" I am of the mind to keep this as an indicator and have seperate subscriptions this would then allow different denouncing/throttling etc - weekly may have different filtering to yearly. As much as I worry about performance it shouldn't convolute the code, or make it inflexible to easily add scenarios. This is really clicking now thank you.

Comment: Re: casting, the array casting in `GetCrossovers`, and the `ToList` call in `ThresholdDetection`.

Comment: For multiple subscriptions, it probably makes sense to use the `Publish` function, though depending on how your code is structured.